# Is there a way to make lowpoly characters close to looking like anime?

Tags: character, 3d-modeling, makehuman

I have never used MakeHuman but i am trying to find a way to make lowpoly human models for a game. simple game so thats why i want lowpoly.

I want to have lowpoly but be looking like anime (Japanese Cartoons).

FYI: Im using Blender and Unity for the game. i just hope i can make anime from makehuman.
[image: Lowpoly anime character]
[image: lowpoly]

Comment: What qualities do you consider something looking like anime? Big eyes? Big head? Or colours?

Comment: Steven ill put a picture in the question help out.

Answer (score 2):

Low poly or high poly, the way to get a model to look like a cartoon is all in the *shader material.*  You're looking for a Toon Shader, such as [this one](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21288).

Comment: Based on the images provided I see no evidence of toon shading just flat areas of colour.

Comment: There are a number of ways a custom shader can be written and qualify as a toon shader (the image in the asker's post was not present when I wrote my answer).  Taking the images into account, those models look like they have a custom lighting model as well, which *may* be "full bright" (e.g. no lighting information used).  Achieving a cell-shading style lighting is just another aspect of the shader.  [Shader Forge](http://acegikmo.com/shaderforge/) has nodes for this: [example](http://www.acegikmo.com/shaderforge/images/web/maininputs/main_input_customlighting.gif).